# Passing different images every second Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Trying to pass dynamically different image every second `Fragment` and I have trouble to set it properly in `onCreateView` method and `if` statement. All images are stored in drawable file.

Name for this second layout is `maps`and `ImageView id` is  `android:id="@+id/map_images"`

Fragment

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    String stringValue;
    int imagesResId;
    TextView text;
    String[] rbData;
    RadioGroup radioButtons;
    boolean mapImage;
    View answer;

    public Fragment1(String str, int imageView , String[] rb, boolean arg) {
        this.stringValue = str;
        this.imagesResId = imageView;
        this.rbData = rb;
        this.mapImage = arg;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i("x","onCreateViewFragment");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
        text =  view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView imageResId = view.findViewById(image);
        answer = view.findViewById((R.id.radioGroup));
        ImageView maps  = view.findViewById(map_images);

        text.setText(stringValue);
        imageResId.setImageResource(imagesResId);
        maps.                                            //HERE

        if (mapImage) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.maps, container, false);
            maps = view.findViewById(map_images);
            maps.                                         //HERE
        } else {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
            text =  view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            radioButtons = view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
            text.setText(stringValue);
            imageResId.setImageResource(imagesResId);

            //checkboxes, textviews, imageviews, etc
        }

        if (answer != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < radioButtons.getChildCount(); i++) {
                ((RadioButton) radioButtons.getChildAt(i)).setText(rbData[i]);
            }
        }

        return view;
    }
```

MainActivity

```
fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    fragmentList.add(new Fragment1(getResources().getString(R.string.text_page_1), R.drawable.swans, new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.answer1), getResources().getString(R.string.answer2),getResources().getString(R.string.answer3)},false));
    fragmentList.add(new Fragment1(null, R.drawable.image_file, null, true));    // TALKING ABOUT THIS LINE HERE AND LATER EVERY SECOND FRAGMENT. JUST IMAGE WILL CHANGE.
    fragmentList.add(new Fragment1(getResources().getString(R.string.text_page_2), R.drawable.nature, new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.answer4), getResources().getString(R.string.answer5),getResources().getString(R.string.answer6)},false));
```

The layout

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eY6qy.jpg)

Here is my viewPager and `fragmentList` you ask about

```
    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {                             //Line 3


    List<Fragment> fragmentList;                                                    //Line 4

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragmentList) {          //Line 5
        super(fm);                                                                  //Line 6
        this.fragmentList = fragmentList;                                           //Line 7
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {                                         //Line 8
        return fragmentList.get(position);                                          //Line 9
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {                                                         //Line 10
        return fragmentList.size();                                                 //Line 11
    }
}
```

So how to change dynamically this layout with data using a viewPager?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do here.In this line  `ImageView imageResId = view.findViewById(image);` what is `image`? `And ImageView maps  = view.findViewById(map_images);` what is `map_images`. They should be valid `id's` in `fragment_1.xml`. and should be used like R.id.image or R.id.map_images

Comment: Hello. thanks for interest. So this `image` is the ID name in `Fragment_1.xml` file for `ImageView`. The `map_images` is the ID name in `maps.xml` for `ImageView`. So there are two `ImageView` - one for `Fragment_1` with text and radioButtons  AND second `ImageView` is for also `Fragment_1` BUT only for layout with map itself. Please have a look at enclosed layout picture at the end of my post.

Comment: So all what is problematic here is how to properly display different images every second Fragments. The rest works

Comment: @MissAndroid I think you are complicating a simple thing. You should use a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html) for your purpose.  May I know why you are creating a `List` of `Fragment` ? Also post error if you are getting any. BTW you don't have to inflate two different layout for your case, you can do it using only one layout.

Comment: I've updated my post with `viewPager` class. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass data `Fragment` from `Activity`, try to use static static factory method as the following codes.

**Fragment1**

```
public static Fragment newInstance(String str, int imageView , String[] rb, boolean arg) {
    Fragment fragment = new Fragment1();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("str", str);
    args.putInt("image_resid", imageView);
    args.putStringArray("rb", rb);
    args.putBoolean("arg", arg);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Bundle args = getArguments();
    stringValue = args.getString("str");
    imagesResId = args.getInt("image_resid");
    rbData = args.getStringArray("rb");
    mapImage = args.getBoolean("arg");
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
fragmentList.add(Fragment1.newInstance(getResources().getString(R.string.text_page_1), R.drawable.swans, new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.answer1), getResources().getString(R.string.answer2),getResources().getString(R.string.answer3)},false));
fragmentList.add(Fragment1.newInstance(null, R.drawable.image_file, null, true));    // TALKING ABOUT THIS LINE HERE AND LATER EVERY SECOND FRAGMENT. JUST IMAGE WILL CHANGE.
fragmentList.add(Fragment1.newInstance(getResources().getString(R.string.text_page_2), R.drawable.nature, new String[]{getResources().getString(R.string.answer4), getResources().getString(R.string.answer5),getResources().getString(R.string.answer6)},false));
```

Comment: Great kim, it's really helpful but it doesnt really answer my question :( I appreciate your help though.